# VIM keybindings in Google Cloud Shell Editor?

Tags: vim, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

Did anyone figure out if Google Cloud Shell Editor has vim key bindings? If so, how do you turn them on?

I've been googling, clicking through the whole app, and can't find any information on whether it has vim key bindings or not. 
Most online editors have it, including Cloud9. Would be weird if google excluded the key bindings.

Comment: Do you just mean in the shell environment, you can use the typical: set -o vi

Comment: No. That's not what I mean. I mean the cloud shell editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see it is not currently supported. It is based on VS Code which does not support VIM Key Bindings by default. There is a VS Code Extension that can add VIM Keybindings, but Extensions are not supported for download in Google Cloud Shell.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations